# Supress Caution: quantization tables are too coarse for baseline JPEG

Tags: libjpeg, libtiff

I have a custom built libtiff with jpg support. When I create TIFF images using JPG compression with a low quality, like 10, I get the following warning printed to stderr:

`Caution: quantization tables are too coarse for baseline JPEG`

I am looking to suppress this warning. I know it is an issue, but the intent of these is a super small quick look image before the full size image is created, so it is meaningless under the circumstance and floods stderr.

What I don't know is, is there a mechanism to suppress these via the TIFF interface or am I going to have to recompile the libraries and set a field, and if so, is there a CMake option I missed, or do I need to modify code.